# Center window title by XML

Tags: android, xml, android-theme, android-styles, android-titlebar

I'm developing an android app, and I would like to center the window title in the title bar.

I'm using a custom theme.

styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme"> 
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">45dp</item>
</style>
```

themes.xml:

```
<style name="CustomTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">@color/customblue</item>       
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
    ...
</activity>
```

The only ways I found were using java code to center the title, or defining the title bar as a `RelativeLayout` with a `TextView` inside of it. I would like to use just styles/themes.

Is there a way to make the title centered using only styles?

Comment: have a custom layout center the view set it to actionbar

Comment: @Raghunandan As I wrote, I would like to do it just with styles/themes, without additional layouts/views, and without java code.

Comment: Just with styles not sure. I think its a no unless some one has a workaround

Comment: @Raghunandan At least without java code. I have several activities, I want that style to be the default one for all activities, without having to specify it in the activity code

Comment: you creaete a base Activtiy apply the custom layout to the actionbar. Then extend other activites with BaseActivity.